# What should I do with these Javascript-console errors (Wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, console.log, jquery-migrate

```
reset.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

jquery-migrate.js:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1

jquery-migrate.js:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:45

jquery-migrate.js:47 console.trace
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate.js:47

reset.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

More info:

Some of my plugins' Javascript is not working but only on the home page. I've tried disabling all non-related plugins but this doesn't solve the problem.

jquery-migrate.js appears to be located in `wp-includes/js/jquery/`. I'm assuming this is the correct file location.

In the very beginning I including a file called reset.css but long ago deleted the file plus any reference to it (for example, in functions.php) so I'm not sure what the issue is there. It is correct that the file is not available but it also shouldn't be looking for it.

Can any tell me step by step what I need to do/change? If any other info necessary please ask! Many thanks.

EDIT: after deactivating debugging in wp-config the console changed to this:

```
GET http://match.onesquad.nl/wp-content/themes/match-theme/reset.css 

jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:23 JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1

jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45 JQMIGRATE: jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated

migrateWarn @   jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:45

jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)  @   jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:560

(anonymous) @   (index):368

i   @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

fireWith    @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

ready   @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

K   @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:47 console.trace

migrateWarn @   jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:47

jQuery.fn.(anonymous function)  @   jquery-migrate.js?ver=1.4.1:560

(anonymous) @   (index):368

i   @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

fireWith    @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

ready   @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2

K   @   jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:2
```

Comment: Looks like issues in your `<head>`. Like `<link href='check this here' />` or `<style>look in here</style>`, and `<script src='here here'></script>`.

Comment: OK great, here's my <head> info... Anything strange in there? 
`<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <meta name="description" content="">
 <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>Match International B.V.</title>
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <?php wp_head();?>
</head>`

Comment: Is there a `style.css` file in your `template_url`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with `template_url`... I only have a `style.css` in my theme's root folder.

Comment: I disabled jquery-migrate.js with the following code: `/* No JQ Migrate - http://subinsb.com/remove-jquery-migrate-in-wp-blog */
add_filter( 'wp_default_scripts', 'removeJqueryMigrate' );
function removeJqueryMigrate(&$scripts){
 if(!is_admin()){
  $scripts->remove('jquery');
  $scripts->add('jquery', false, array('jquery-core'), '1.10.2');
 }
}` in functions.php. This has erased the errors and I don't get any (other than for reset.css) in its place, so I guess this file doesn't have anything to do with my Javascript plugin conflicts... Hmm.

Comment: `href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>`??? `template_directory` and `template_url` are the same thing. [Read up on it here.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/)